# How to convert hovering navicon to clickable/toggling?

Tags: html, css

I have created a page with a navicon . When I hover through the navicon it displays horizontally arranged menu . I want the navicon to be clickable/toggling .

Comment: Here is the link of jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/czdn6nmd/

Comment: Please, post the code *in the question*, not just a link as it may get unaccessible in time... If possible, add a code snippet to the question (Ctrl + M)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work ... http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use jQuery or JS.

Here is a JQuery version: http://jsfiddle.net/czdn6nmd/4/

EDIT: to ensure the menu shows again on desktop you should toggle a class instead:

just changed the mobile version of the ul in the nav to display none initially and block on active.

```
nav ul {
    display: none;
}
nav ul.active {
    display: block;
}
```

Then added the toggling JQuery:

```
$("#menu-icon").on("click", function(){
    $(this).siblings("ul").toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Thanks it is working in the jsfiddle . But where to add those jquery code? In the html or css?

Comment: You will ideally need to add it in a separate JS file with the code wrapped in a function to check if the document is ready (http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) then include the JS into your page (<script src="myscripts.js"></script>). Or you can put it in the foot (recommended rather than in the head) of the HTML page inside script tags. The choice is yours: (http://javascript.info/tutorial/adding-script-html)

Comment: No actually I have used jquery many a times. I have included the jquery code in the html page itself using script tag but its not working!

Comment: have you put it in the on document ready function and have you included the JQuery library JS file?

Comment: Yep! other jqueries are working.But this isn't!!

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('hellojh')
  $("#menu-icon").on("click", function(){
    $(this).siblings("ul").toggleClass("active");
});
  </script>

Comment: alert message is getting displayed.

Comment: Depending on where you are putting that in your page, top or bottom, you are going to need to wrap that whole function in a $( document ).ready() function. If the page isn't there when it runs it won't set up the event. So <script type="text/javascript"> $( document ).ready(function() { $("#menu-icon").on("click", function(){                   $(this).siblings("ul").toggleClass("active"); }); }); </script>

Comment: I have included it at the bottom just before the </body> tag.

Comment: Have you wrapped it in the document ready? I'm afraid without seeing the page I can't really help much more. As long as your JQuery library is included before the script and is running correctly, you have the code wrapped in the document ready and in the correct place, then this should work. As you can see, it works in jsfiddle (even with version 1.9.1 of JQuery), so logically it will be an issue of loading it in correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you need to diable the hoover

maybe be dublication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041207/how-to-disable-on-hover-effects-of-a-link or atleast you can get the infos there.

for example

```
a:hover {
 text-decoration:none;
}
```

then you need to add a click event

```
onclick="yourFunction"
```